# Debugging using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (Free version)

Tags: debugging, visual-c++-2010

I have C code which I am debugging using MS-Visual C++ 2010 (free version). In the code some variables are declared and used inside a local scope code block which is defined by parenthesis
`{... }`

But while debugging the debugger does not show the values in watch window, for all the variables which are declared inside this code block, even when the code execution point is inside the code block. It says "Error : symbol not found". this is very much a handicap for me while debugging this code.

When I move the declaration of one particular such variable to beginning of the function, by removing from the `{}`code block , the debugger is able to show me its values properly.

1. What is the reason for this quirky behaviour? Is it the free version causing this?
2. Without making code changes, using some project settings etc, how can I see the values of such local code block scope variables in debugger watch window?

Comment: Is this a release build? MSVC will alias variables in release builds, if their lifetime doesn't overlap. Also, does the "Immediate" window work with such variables?

Comment: @MSalters: No. This is Debug build. By immediate window, I guess you mean 'mouse over' the variable. This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Replying here because I don't see this problem addressed anywhere.

Go to your project property page and look at the Optimization property in the C/C++ section. If optimization is on, some of your variables are getting optimized away. 
When this happens - and it's pretty common - there is no variable to inspect, so you get the error message "symbol not found", and it won't show up in your locals or auto window. Change the Optimization property to Disabled, rebuild, and see if the problem is solved. It probably will be.

If optimization is important to your project, I'd do my development with it turned off, but set it back to what you want periodically to test. Sometimes turning optimization on will break something, and if that happens you want to have some idea of what you've changed lately, because otherwise it can be real hard to find the problem.